# Calcuation $Stab_G$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider action of $X=GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $A\cdot v = Av$.

I'm trying to deteiminate $Stab_X(H)$ were $H$ is some one-dimensional linear space  of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

How should I approach this question?

Answer (score 0):

First observe that the stabilizer of a line $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the same as the stabilizer of a non-zero vector $v\in H$, i.e. Stab$_X(H)=$Stab$_X(v)$. This is true since the action is linear.

Now for $v=(x,y,z)$, direct computation shows that $$H=\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3\\ b_1&b_2&b_3\\ c_1&c_2&c_3\end{bmatrix}\in GL_3\quad\big|\quad a_1x+a_2y+a_3z=x, b_1x+b_2y+b_3c=y, c_1x+c_2y+c_3z=z\Bigg\}$$

I don't know if that is the expression you want.